# Swing bug or just strange behaviour?

Tags: java, swing

Supposedly swing actions are read by components to configure their properties. One of these properties being 'enabled'. 
I've found either 'enabled' only refers to the actual gui interaction or that jcombox has a bug, because if set with a disabled action, it can still trigger it by for instance using setSelectedItem(int).

So do i need to have a dumb guard in my actions actionperformed method doing 'if not enabled return'?

Comment: If I recall right, enabled/disabled controls the GUI interaction with the component.  If an event related to the item was triggered to the code, its listener will pick it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JCombobox inherits from JComponent.  The documentation (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/jcomponent.html) says

> void setEnabled(boolean)    Set whether the component is enabled. An
>   enabled component can respond to user input and generate events.

I admit it's not clear, but I think the "user" input means that it can still be set programmatically.